# Neater way to handle requests in node?

Tags: node.js

This is the code I am using to grab data:

```
let user = await axios.get(`${base_api_url}/users/${req.params.username}`, options)
let events = await axios.get(`${base_api_url}/users/${req.params.username}/events`, options)

res.json({
    success:true,
    user: user.data,
    events: events.data
})
```

I like how neat this is but the downside to this is that I can't handle errors. Any ideas?

Comment: Why can't you handle errors?

Comment: Clearly im asking this question because I didnt know the right way to do it.

Comment: to me it seemed like you were unaware that error handling even existed for async/await... but that's pretty easy to find on the web... so i didn't want to assume you didn't look for it.

Answer (score 1):

You just need `try/catch` around your `await` as that's how you catch promise rejections when using `await`.

```
try {
    let user = await axios.get(`${base_api_url}/users/${req.params.username}`, options)
    let events = await axios.get(`${base_api_url}/users/${req.params.username}/events`, options)

    res.json({
        success:true,
        user: user.data,
        events: events.data
    })
} catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
    // decide what to do here when you get an error
    res.status(500).send("axios error")'
}
```

**Run Requests In Parallel**

FYI, you don't need to sequence your two axios calls one after the other.  You could likely speed things up a bit with `Promise.all()`:

```
 Promise.all([
     axios.get(`${base_api_url}/users/${req.params.username}`, options),
     axios.get(`${base_api_url}/users/${req.params.username}/events`, options)
 ]).then(([user, events]) => {
    res.json({
        success:true,
        user: user.data,
        events: events.data
    });
 }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
    res.sendStatus(500);
 });
```

or:

```
try {
     let [user, events] = await Promise.all([
         axios.get(`${base_api_url}/users/${req.params.username}`, options),
         axios.get(`${base_api_url}/users/${req.params.username}/events`, options)
     ]);
     res.json({
         success:true,
         user: user.data,
         events: events.data
} catch(err) {
     console.log(err);
     res.sendStatus(500);
}
```

Comment: @Syn - Also, see how you can run these requests in parallel to get better performance.  Or, you could use `await` with `Promise.all()` too, but it didn't seem necessary here.